# Why @auth0/angular-jwt not woking for Angular9?

Tags: angular

I tried to install `@auth0/angular-jwt`for angular9 project.

**module.ts**

```
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,   
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        allowedDomains: ["example.com"],
        disallowedRoutes: ["http://example.com/examplebadroute/"],
      },
    }),
  ]
```

but when run the program it give me following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADPVM.png)

[@auth0/angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick look at the @auth0/angular-jwt npm site:

```
Supported Angular versions

This project only supports the actively supported versions of Angular as stated in the Angular documentation. Whilst other versions might be compatible they are not actively supported
```

The active versions of Angular are 13 and above:
https://angular.io/guide/releases#actively-supported-versions